# If Jannah has levels and all wishes will be granted then couldn't a person wish himself to top level?

Tags: jannah, belief, hereafter

What the title says! It's very clear that there are levels, and higher levels have the best things/status. And if you are living in a lower level couldn't you just wish to be in the top most level. But I read that only top level persons would be able to bring their friend in upper levels not the other way around. And I also read that lower levels one would see top levels like stars.

Comment: If everyone could wish for the highest rank of jannah then it’d be unfair for the Muslims who stay within the very teachings of Islam. Of course you could wish for it but Allah wouldn’t hand it to you without you putting the effort in. Insha’allah all of us Muslims will reach the highest ranks

Comment: so not all wishes in jannah would be answered?

Comment: Allah decides if your duaa is answered brother, but you must earn the highest rank of jannah. It isn’t simply going to get given to you. Allah accepts all duaas that will be beneficial to you.

Comment: Questions that I didn't ask: What should I do to get into highest level? Or Why there are levels in Jannah? ..... The question I HAVE asked is: If all wishes will be answered in Jannah then would the wish to get to a better level also be accepted? .... You can say yes, or no but that would mean there are some wishes that won't be accepted. Either way give a source, not really interested in opinions.